# Searchbar cancel button text is truncated

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, ios11, uisearchcontroller

Having various problems setting up the UISearchBar to work properly. It should be shown in the navigationBar. Using the "old" way setting `navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar`. As seen on the picture below, the Cancel button text is truncated. Any ideas how to solve this problem? I have tried to set `searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()` with no luck.

```
fileprivate lazy var searchController: UISearchController = {
        let sc = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)
        sc.delegate = self
        sc.searchBar.delegate = self
        sc.searchBar.returnKeyType = .done
        sc.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
        sc.searchResultsUpdater = self
        sc.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        sc.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        return sc
    } ()
```

[image]

Comment: how do you add it to the navigation bar?

Comment: I'm using `navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar`

Comment: try if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        } else {
            navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
            searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit() }

Comment: @Dan I have a similar issue, did you manage to get it to work?